# How to fetch relational data in parse(Back4App) using flutter/dart?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart, back4app

I have 2 tables in parse: `User` and `Location`. Location has a column name `userId` which is related to `User's ObjectId`. I manually added the relation in `Location` just for testing. But I'm having trouble fetching the location.

**User**

```
|objectId|name |
|--------| --- |
|abc123  | Sta |
|def456  |Danny|
```

**Location**

```
|objectId| geopoint |     userId    |
|--------|----------|---------------|
|someid  |12.3, 45.6|view relation|
```

**Code**

```
var locationObject = ParseObject('Location');
var userObject = ParseObject('User');

var queryUser = QueryBuilder(userObject)
      ..whereValueExists('objectId', true);
var queryLoc = QueryBuilder(locationObject)
      ..whereMatchesQuery('userId', queryUser);

var result = await queryLoc.query();

print(result.result); // output: null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can looking for user manually by its id:

```dart
final queryLoc = QueryBuilder(locationObject)
      ..equals('userId', userId); // add your `userId`.
```

Also, you can auth to Parse on app start by using method `login` from Parse Flutter SDK (at first time you need to request login and password from your user, in other ways you can extract Parse user from cache).

Registration (you should add your `user`, `password` and `email` parameters):

```dart
final user =  ParseUser().create('user', 'password', 'user@email.com');

final authResponse = await user.login();
if (response.success){
  user = response.result;
} else {
  // Login error, handle this
}
```

Login:

```dart
final user = ParseUser.currentUser();
```